# I need to convert a sentence into pig latin using an input file

Tags: java, file

I am supposed to write a program that converts entire phrases into [pig latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin). It should read in phrases from a file, and then translate and print out in pig latin form.

This must read in text from a file.
There should be NO input from the keyboard.

This is my sample file text:

> This is a test
>
> Here is a second line
>
> and a third

The output should be the original phrase followed by its pig latin version. Both versions should be surrounded by quotes in the output.

> "This is a test" in pig latin is "is-Thay is-way a-way est-tay "
>
> "Here is a second line" in pig latin is "ere-Hay is-way a-way
>   econd-say ine-lay "
>
> "and a third" in pig latin is "and-way a-way ird-thay "

I have changed a few things and now I can output a sentence but not more than one. How would I get more than one line of output. How would I get the scanner to go to the next line?

What I have now is the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class pigLatin2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("phrases.txt"));

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\"" + line + "\"" + " in pig latin is \"");
            Scanner words = new Scanner(line);
            while (words.hasNext()) {
                String word = words.next();
                String pigLatin = pigLatinWord(word);
                System.out.print(pigLatin + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\"");
        }
    }


    public static String pigLatinWord(String s) {
        String pigWord;
        if (isVowel(s.charAt(0))) {
            pigWord = s + "-way";
        } else if (s.startsWith("th") || s.startsWith("Th")) {      // or (s.toUpperCase().startsWith("TH"))
            pigWord = s.substring(2) + "-" + s.substring(0,2) + "ay";
        } else {
            pigWord = s.substring(1,s.length()) + "-" + s.charAt(0) + "ay";
        }
        return pigWord;
    }


    public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
        return (vowels.indexOf(c) >= 0);    // when index of c in vowels is not -1, c is a vowel
    }
}
```

which outputs, "This is a test" in pig latin is "is-Thay is-way a-way est-tay "

Answer (score 2):

You are reading just one word here:

```
    Scanner words = new Scanner(line);
    String word = words.next();
    String pigLatin = pigLatinWord(word);
```

Try this:

```
    Scanner words = new Scanner(line);
    String pigLatin = "";
    while(words.hasNext()){
        String word = words.next();
        pigLatin += pigLatinWord(word) + " ";
    }
```

If you know something about string concatenating, use `StringBuilder` here instead.

Comment: Thank you, I changed a few things and now I can read in one line of pig latin. How would I get it to read more than one line?

Comment: Your code above works perfectly, all lines are printed, I cant see the problem @kmlepley

Comment: Maybe try to close scanner: `input.close()` at the end of the `main` method, but I don't think this is the problem @kmlepley

Comment: you're right, I just didn't have more than one line in my input file. thank you very much!